# Rails, turbolinks and javascript. How to avoid duplicate Switchery button appear?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, switchery

I'm implementing Switchery button in my Rails app and Turbolinks is on. When I navigate to another page, and then click the back button, the button is being duplicated.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
var switchery = new Switchery(elem, {className:"switchery switchery-small"});
});
```

Html view:

```
<b>Assign as administrator?<span> <%= f.check_box :admin, class:"js-switch" %></span></b>
```

Screenshot:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePJdk.png)

So how can i handle this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

[Multiple calls](https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery#multiple-calls) prevents switchery being called twice on the same element but it's not helpful with turbolinks. As page is fetched from cache, it's click/change events needs to re-initialized when they are added to DOM. The only way I found was to remove the existing elements (it looks like they are just visual elements anyway) and then re-initialize them. turbolinks:load function becomes something like this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(e) {
  // Delete existing switches if there are any...
  $(".switchery").remove();
  // As we removed all the switchery elements, we need fetch all of them again.
  var els = document.querySelectorAll(".js-switch");
  els.forEach(function(el) {
    new Switchery(el);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple calls](https://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/)

You can filter out existing elements that have already been called by looking for data-switchery="true".

```js
  var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch:not([data-switchery])');
```

Comment: your suggestion does avoid button being duplicated, however, the switchery button is locked and unable to trigger.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the switchery elements from the page during the `turbolinks:unload` event

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same. The button is fine when navigating between pages by clicking the links. It will not when clicking the back button. Is there any other way to trigger the button when navigate to current page?